# Create a sticky column in row with 2 columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to create a row that consists of 2 columns in Bootstrap.
When I scroll I only want the second column to be sticky.
As far as I can see this is impossible because the container for the sticky column is the row and when the row disappears the sticky column also disappears.
I've created a codepen to show you what I mean.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-xs-14">
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    <div class="article_preview_date">DATE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 ml-auto">
    <div class="sticky">
      STICKY
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/baelen-git/pen/abdKJVQ

Does anyone have an idea how to create the desired functionality?

Comment: You're correct. Position sticky is always relevant to the parent / container div. What you could do is use a bit of JS to pickup when you've reached the element and change it's position to `fixed` as you scroll over it.

Comment: I agree. And i don't know why you use `sticky` for that UI. You can define position for it to make it's always show when you scroll up. Like a floating button or something. if you have to do that, yeah, JS i think is a good solution for that. I agree with @vansch